# Como crear una consulta nativa en la que llame un procedimiento almacenado

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedure, powerbi

Mi pregunta radica principalmente en que no encuentro una solución de como hacer uso de un procedimiento almacenado por medio del método de conectividad de datos Direct Query para Power BI, es decir, quiero hacer un reporte en Power BI usando Direct Query para si conjunto de datos esta en un procedimiento almacenado.

Leyendo y consultando durante varios días he encontrado una posible solución (aquí me dirán si es la mas optima para mi caso) es crear una consulta nativa la cual llame el procedimiento almacenado, esto con el fin de hacer uso no del procedimiento almacenado si no de la consulta nativa desde Power BI.

El procedimiento almacenado con el que cuento para hacer la consulta nativa así como lo estoy pensando es el siguiente:

```
ALTER  proc [dbo].[TravelsCustomers]
@TypeOp int=0,
@Customer   varchar(50)

as
begin
    set nocount on

    SELECT  Estatus,
            ClaveCustomer
            Lote,
            Address,
            OC
    Into    #Response
    FROM    TravelVw V
    WHERE   Estatus = 'PROGRESS'
    and     TypeOp = Case when @TypeOp = 0 then TypeOp
                                When @TypeOp = 1 then 'FLASH'
                                When @TypeOp = 2 then 'SMALL'
                            End
    and     isnull(@Customer, '0') in ('0', ClaveCustomer)  
    and     TypeOp != 'SALE'


    Select  V.*,  I2.Coment, I2.MODIFIEDBY, I2.CreatedDateTime
    From    #Response   V
    left join (Select   I.Travel, 
                        isnull(I.Coment, '-') Coment,
                        I.ModifiedBy,
                        DATEADD(MINUTE, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, GETUTCDATE(),GETDATE()), I.CreatedDateTime) CreatedDateTime
             From   dbo.Travel I 
             Where  I.CREATEDDATETIME = (   Select MAX(CREATEDDATETIME) 
                                            From dbo. I3
                                            Where I.Travel = I3.Travel
                                        )
             ) I2 on V.Travel = I2.Travel

end
```

Aquí quisiera contar con el apoyo de ustedes ya sea para generar la consulta nativa o para darme una mejor opción en cuanto el uso de procedimiento almacenados con Direct Query desde Power BI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se trata de un viejo bug de Power BI, que aún no se ha corregido. Una vez me encontré con este problema y la única forma de solventarlo fue mediante el uso de [OPENROWSET](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openrowset-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), aunque luego me di cuenta que podía crear una función en lugar de un procedimiento, te indico las dos opciones aunque la segunda es más sencilla.

**Utilizando Openrowset**

Si vas al editor avanzado de la consulta en Power Query, puedes sustituir la consulta original por

```
let
    Origen = Sql.Database("localhost", "TuBaseDeDatos", [Query="select *
from
openrowset('SQLOLEDB','SERVER=localhost;Trusted_Connection=yes;',' set fmtonly off;exec TuBaseDeDatos..TravelsCustomers 1, "0001"')"])

in
    Origen
```

Pero normalmente los servidores de SQL Server no suelen incluir el permiso para ejecutar OPENROWSET, así que es necesario habilitar primero el permiso, ejecuntando en el SQL Server Management Studio lo siguiente:

```
sp_configure 'show advanced options',1
reconfigure with override
go
sp_configure 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries',1
reconfigure with override
go
```

Supongo que necesitas que la consulta sea dinámica, para ello debes convertir la consulta en una función y previamente crear los dos parámetros, pero eso se escapa del ámbito de la respuesta.

**Utilizando una función de tabla de SQL Server**

Otra forma de realizar tu objetivo es no utilizar procedimientos almacenados y en vez de eso pasarlo a una función de tabla en SQL Server, aunque la utilización de tablas temporales no es posible y por ello es mejor utilizar una variable de tabla, en tu caso seria algo así:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnTravelsCustomers]
(   
    @TypeOp int=0,
    @Customer varchar(50)
)
RETURNS @Response table (Estatus varchar(50), ClaveCustomer varchar(50), Lote varchar(50), Address varchar(150), OC varchar(50), Coment varchar(250), MODIFIEDBY varchar(100), CreatedDateTime datetime) 
AS
begin
   declare @ResponsePre table (Estatus varchar(50), ClaveCustomer varchar(50), Lote varchar(50), Address varchar(150), OC varchar(50))

   Insert into @ResponsePre (Estatus, ClaveCustomer, Lote, Address, OC)
    SELECT  Estatus,
            ClaveCustomer
            Lote,
            Address,
            OC
    FROM    TravelVw V
    WHERE   Estatus = 'PROGRESS'
    and     TypeOp = Case when @TypeOp = 0 then TypeOp
                                When @TypeOp = 1 then 'FLASH'
                                When @TypeOp = 2 then 'SMALL'
                            End
    and     isnull(@Customer, '0') in ('0', ClaveCustomer)  
    and     TypeOp != 'SALE'

    insert into @Response table (Estatus, ClaveCustomer, Lote, Address, OC, Coment, MODIFIEDBY, CreatedDateTime)
    Select  V.Estatus, V.ClaveCustomer, V.Lote, V.Address, V.OC, I2.Coment, I2.MODIFIEDBY, I2.CreatedDateTime
    From    @ResponsePre V
    left join (Select   I.Travel, 
                        isnull(I.Coment, '-') Coment,
                        I.ModifiedBy,
                        DATEADD(MINUTE, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, GETUTCDATE(),GETDATE()), I.CreatedDateTime) CreatedDateTime
             From   dbo.Travel I 
             Where  I.CREATEDDATETIME = (   Select MAX(CREATEDDATETIME) 
                                            From dbo. I3
                                            Where I.Travel = I3.Travel
                                        )
             ) I2 on V.Travel = I2.Travel
)
return
end
GO
```

Luego te vas al editor avanzado de Power Query y cambias la sentencia de la consulta por:

```
let
    Origen= Sql.Database("localhost", "TuBaseDeDatos", [Query="select *
from dbo.fnTravelsCustomers(1, '0001')"])

in
    Origen
```

Cambias "localhost" por la IP o el nombre de instancia de tu SQL Server y "TuBaseDeDatos" por el nombre de tu base de datos.

Una vez más , para hacerlo dinámico tienes que cambiar los valores por parámetros, que puedes definir.

Lo he escrito al vuelo, sin realizar comprobaciones, así es que puede que tenga algún pequeño error de sintaxis.

Comment: Al parecer estoy teniendo algunos problemas con la sintaxis del código que me compartes empezando por el `declare` el cual me muestra como mensaje de error `Incorrect syntax near 'declare'. Expecting '(', SELECT, or WITH` adicional a esto también me genera mensaje de error al hacer uso de los parametros de entrada en el `WHERE` me indica lo siguiente `Must declare the scalar variable @TypeOP`, alguna sugerencia para corregir esto ?

Comment: He modificado el código de la función, pruébalo.

Comment: Sigo teniendo error de sintaxis al momento de hacer uso de los parámetros `Must declare the scalar variable @TypeOP` y como comentario adicional veo que te sobra un paréntesis al final antes de `return`, no se si se este de deba abrir previamente en algún punto

Comment: Alguna novedad respecto al error de sintaxis que queda pendiente por resolver ?

Comment: He editado la función, espero que no tengas más probelams